# Virtual Host Configuration and mod_rewrite - Removing PHP Extension and Adding Forward Slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

On my production server, things are fine: PHP extension removal and trailing slash rules are in place in my `.htaccess` file.

But locally, this isn't working (well, partially, anyway). I'm running Apache2 with a virtual host for the site in question. I decided to not use the `.htaccess` file in this case and just add the rules to the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file instead, which, I've heard, if possible on your server, is a better way to go.

The virtual host is working and the URL I use for my site is like this:

`devserver:9090`

Here is my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:9090

# for stuff other than this site
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampstack/apache2/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

# for site in question
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampstack/apache2/htdocs/devserver"
    ServerName devserver

    <Directory "/opt/lampstack/apache2/htdocs/devserver">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule rewrite_module>
        RewriteEngine ON    

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1.php

    </IfModule>

    # error docs
    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I go to directories on the site, I get a 404 error. So for example, this:

`devserver:9090/page.php`

goes to

`devserver:9090/page/`

but going to a directory (that has an `index.php`):

`devserver:9090/dir/`

throws 404 error page.

If I type in `devserver:9090/dir/index.php` I get `devserver:9090/dir/index/` and the contents I want appear...

Can anyone help me with my rewrite rules?

**NOTE**

See my answer below

50 points to anyone who can shed additional light on this answer. I started a bounty and then found my answer but am still learning so any good tips can be worth +50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
```

to this:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

and now it works as expected... Here is the rule I went with to remove PHP extension:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampstack/apache2/htdocs/devserver">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine ON    

    # remove PHP extension
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1.php

    # add trailing slash to all URLs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=302,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone will get a more detailed answer for this particular case, but as a more general advice, you can use the `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` directives to get detailled information about which rule is processed and what is the result of the rewriting.

With that information, you'll be able to find the missing rule, or at least, send us the log output to have more details.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I do have rewrite logs and I'm looking at them right now.

Comment: I discovered some interesting things when peaking into these logs. Basically, I reverted back to no rules, confirmed everything was working as expected, eg, going `example.com/dir/` actually gave my the index and now I'm building up, one rule at a time. I'm still stuck, but your advice was definitely worth +1. Thanks.